# MySQL JSON_OBJECT + CONCAT & GROUP_CONCAT as alias & truncating / Max Length

Tags: mysql, json, alias

I'm trying to pull some relational info into a JSON string via MySQL. However, the method that I'm using seems to truncate the returned value.

Does MyQSL enforce some kind of max string length for queries using `CONCAT` / `GROUP_CONCAT` / `JSON_OBJECT` ? Can I override this?

```
(SELECT
    CONCAT(
        '[',
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                JSON_OBJECT(
                    'my_key_1', my_table.my_val_1,
                    'my_key_2', my_table.my_val_2,
                    'my_key_3', my_table.my_val_3,
                    'my_key_4', my_table.my_val_4,
                    ## [etc, etc ...]
                )
            ),
        ']' 
    )
    FROM my_table
) AS my_alias
```

Comment: Any chance of a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use JSON_ARRAYAGG instead of GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_OBJECT(
            'my_key_1', my_table.my_val_1,
            'my_key_2', my_table.my_val_2,
            'my_key_3', my_table.my_val_3,
            'my_key_4', my_table.my_val_4,
            ## [etc, etc ...]
        )
    )
FROM my_table
```

GROUP_CONCAT is truncated at @@group_concat_max_len (which defaults to 1024 on MySQL or on MariaDB before 10.2, but you can set with e.g. `SET @@group_concat_max_len=1000000;`); this limit does not apply to JSON_ARRAYAGG.

JSON_ARRAYAGG requires MySQL 5.7.22+ or MariaDB 10.5+

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this helps someone else; for this particular case I was using
CodeIgniter 3. My local version was running on a higher MySQL version and, though a great solution, `JSON_ARRAYAGG` wouldn't work in other environments running below MySQL 5.7

Using the following in my [CI SQL query builder](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) seemed to do the trick in order for me to use `GROUP_CONCAT` for larger returned strings:

```
$this->db->simple_query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=15000');
$sql = "(SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        '{',
            '\"my_key_1\":', a_table.value_1, ',',
            '\"my_key_2\":', a_table.value_2, ',',
            ## etc, etc
        '}'
    )
) AS my_alias
FROM my_table
## WHERE
";

return $this->db->query($sql);
```